# When and how is the .sock file created for a uWSGI, nginx and Django stack

Tags: python, django, sockets, nginx, uwsgi

I know that there are dozens of questions about this that mostly stem from following the official [uWSGI guide](https://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html). I have had troubles with permissions too but the other answers have covered them. I want to better understand how and when the Unix socket/socket file is created. FYI this is on an AWS ec2 instance running the Amazon Linux 2 AMI.

The uWSGI guide instructs you to install nginx, Django and uwsgi. Then test the Django development server and nginx in isolation. Then at [this section](https://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#nginx-and-uwsgi-and-test-py) you test that uWSGI and nginx work together with a tcp/ip socket  for communication. After that, still not involving the Django project at all, they describe how to use Unix sockets rather than the tcp/ip socket for communication between nginx and uWSGI. Following all of the nginx/uWSGI configuration you run the command from the home directory (at least for my particular file structure and Django project, `~/test_project`):

```
uwsgi --socket test_project/test_project.sock --wsgi-file test.py
```

This works fine once some permission issues are dealt with. My questions are: what is `test_project.sock`, when is it created, and which process creates it. My best current understanding is that uWSGI creates it, but why then do we need to incorporate the Django project (here `test_project`) at all? Why not just create the socket outside of the Django project folder? Are we using python syntax and it's a member of some `test_project` object or module?

I know that `test_project.sock` is associated with the Unix socket. I thought that it would be a real file but it doesn't seem to be. Even when I run uWSGI in the background and look in the appropriate directory it is not there. Is it so ephemeral that it only exists when a request is actually being passed from nginx to uWSGI?

Furthermore, without being able to actually see the file (`test_project.sock`) how can I know which permissions are required to access it? I ran some tests and now suspect that it is related to the permissions for the `~/test_project/test_project/wsgi.py` file but I don't have any direct proof.

Comment: It's a Unix socket and it's created by uwsgi. I don't understand your question about "involving the Django project" though.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You are absolutely right. I just assumed that the socket needed to be created in the Django project, but it doesn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the socket, `*.sock` file outside of the Django project. When you do it like that the file will persist after the uWSGI process is concluded. Then you can look at the file and determine the permissions.

I was confused because a lot of tutorials, including the [official uWSGI][1](https://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) tutorial, have the user put the `*.sock` file into the Django project. I am still not sure why that is necessary and why the file doesn't persist in that case.